# Why does the S matrix always contain a factor of $(2\pi)^4?$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, s-matrix-theory

In quantum field theory, one usually defines the scattering amplitude as $$S-1=(2\pi)^4\delta(p_{out}-p_{in})M_{Scattering Amplitude}$$
Where S is the S matrix element for any scattering process. It's interesting to see actually to any order of any perturbation theory, the combination of $(2\pi)^4\delta(p_{out}-p_{in})$ is always there. I think one can regard $S-1$ as the scattering amplitude from the initial state to the final state.

I am curious why does $(2\pi)^4\delta(p_{out}-p_{in})$ always show up and why does one need to divide $S-1$ by $(2\pi)^4\delta(p_{out}-p_{in})$ to get $M$?

ps: I know $\delta(p_{out}-p_{in})$ means four-momentum conservation, but what I don't see is why it shows up always as a whole. It seems like we always do a trivial Fourier transform which leads to that, but I didn't see at which step did we do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just remember the standard good $2 \pi$ conventions:

- every time you have any integral over momentum, put the $2\pi$ in the denominator, $d^dp / (2 \pi)^d$
- every time you have a delta function of momentum, put the $2 \pi$ with it, $(2 \pi)^d \delta^d(p)$

These rules are self-consistent, because whenever you use a delta function to get rid of a momentum integral, the $2\pi$ factors cancel out.

By definition, a connected $S$-matrix element only has one overall delta function in it, reflecting overall four-momentum conservation. So if you followed these rules consistently, there should be a $(2\pi)^4$ with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can you see that in the definition of S-matrix there is an overall delta?

Comment: @UniverseMaintainer There must be an overall delta function, because of energy-momentum conservation. By definition, the part of the $S$-matrix with only _one_ delta function (i.e. not more than one) is called the connected $S$-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The energy momentum conserving delta function comes during the calculation of Feynman rules from the perturbation expansion. It is essentially the same form as an FT, but it is buried in quite a long calculation starting from the contractions of field operators in the perturbation expansion using Wick's theorem. Essentially this means that energy-momentum is conserved at each vertex, and consequently it is conserved overall. I have given a calculation of Feynman rules in Appendix J of [A Construction of Full QED Using Finite Dimensional Hilbert Space](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p27.pdf).